# How to reduce the size of audio apps

Tags: android

I am working on one project, an app that contains audio files**(Audio App)**. But the size of the audio files is much that when I add everything to the app it makes the app so heavy. So is there a way to reduce the audio files or the app itself

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could reduce sound by reducing their bitrate. Also, 'heavy' is a subjective term, what is your expected app size and what is the actual app size?

Comment: I have tried several audio compressors but still not working perfectly. It is a Quranic recitation app, there is only three surahs there and the app size is already 85mb and going to 114 surahs

Comment: At this point, I can only assume that the sound duration would be huge and hence the app size is huge. Also, are you sure sound files are the only things? Edit your question and add the link to the compressors you have used, also build an apk and analyze it. Share the analyzer data here.

Answer (score -2):

Imagine Netflix wanting to put all their movies in their app, it does not make much sense, right? Nor would Calm put all of their music in the app.

I think a better approach would be better to store your files in a server or in an object storage (see S3 or similar), and make an API call to retrieve the file on the app. This call will download the audio file when needed, instead of bundling the audio files as part of the source code. Of course, you can later cache this file as part of the app, or just download it every time (caution with the data consumption!).

There are also audio APIs that do all the heavylifting for you. You just upload/generate the audio file, and you make an API call to retrieve it every time you need it. A good service to do this is [www.api.audio](http://www.api.audio). It will take care of the files storage, file retrieval and CDN caching so you can download your files faster. Hopefully this is useful, and if not, we will be happy to hear what are your needs.
Disclaimer: I work for api.audio

Let me know if you have any questions :)